# mysql workbench not connecting with aws aurora serverless mysql

Tags: mysql-workbench, amazon-aurora

i am getting this error:
`can not connect to database server`

> Your connection attempt failed for user 'cameraworx' from your host to server at cameraworxinstance.cluster-cugucrimdqma.ap-south-1.rds.amazonaws.com:3306:
>     Can't connect to MySQL server on 'cameraworxinstance.cluster-cugucrimdqma.ap-south-1.rds.amazonaws.com' (110)

Please:

1. Check that mysql is running on server cameraworxinstance.cluster-cugucrimdqma.ap-south-1.rds.amazonaws.com
2. Check that mysql is running on port 3306 (note: 3306 is the default, but this can be changed)
3. Check the cameraworx has rights to connect to cameraworxinstance.cluster-cugucrimdqma.ap-south-1.rds.amazonaws.com from your address (mysql rights define what clients can connect to the server and from which machines)
4. Make sure you are both providing a password if needed and using the correct password for cameraworxinstance.cluster-cugucrimdqma.ap-south-1.rds.amazonaws.com connecting from the host address you're connecting from

i am trying to connect with these credentials :

**endpoint**: cameraworxinstance.cluster-cugucrimdqma.ap-south-1.rds.amazonaws.com

**port**: 3306

username: master username

in the vpc security groups i even tried with inbound all traffic

Answer (score 0):

Amazon Aurora Serverless has the following features:

- Amazon Aurora can be used only within the VPC in which it is created and accepts connections only within that VPC in which it is created.
- It will not work in VPN Network or VPC Peering Network.
- By default the port is 3306, you cannot change the port
- There is no DB Parameter Group, instead only Cluster Parameter Group is used.
- Amazon Aurora Serverless Cluster's endpoint can be also accessed through AWS Direct Connect.

  You have also mentioned you have inbound all the traffic in the VPC security groups. This is not the recommended way to connect to a database.
  You have to explicitly mention the source from where the connections will be coming.

  Eg:

  Type                   Protocol   Port Range      Source
  MySQL/Aurora     TCP         3306         security group id

If you do not have a default VPC, you can create a VPC in the Aurora Dashboard, which will create default DB Subnet group and  default security group.

Thanks